# A simpler way of comparing md5 checksum?

Tags: osx, hashsum

After downloading a file that has a md5 checksum available I currently check it with

```
md5 *file* | grep *given_checksum*
```

e.g.

```
md5 file.zip | grep -i B4460802B5853B7BB257FBF071EE4AE2
```

but it seemed funny to me to require grep and the pipe for what is surely a very common task. A stickler for doing things efficiently, I wondered there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of tool is that `md5`? From which package it comes?

Comment: I didn't realise it was any different until I actually asked this question and started looking into the answers, but I'm using bash on OS X and it's Apple's own tool which doesn't have the -c option. Apparently they stopped bundling md5sum in 10.5... I've now installed the original unix md5sum tool.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`md5sum` has a `-c` option to check an existing set of sums, and its exit status indicates success/failure.

Example:

```
$ echo "ff9f75d4e7bda792fca1f30fc03a5303  package.deb" | md5sum -c -
package.deb: OK
```

Find a nice resource [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/442968/10770)

Comment: Thanks. Just for completion, I now use `md5sum -c - <<<"b4460802b5853b7bb257fbf071ee4ae2 file_name.ext"` which seems cleaner than involving grep!

Comment: hmm, not much improvement to the original $ md5 *file* | grep *given_checksum* and if you want to use case insensitive string you have to stick with grep -i

Comment: I was getting `no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found` when I was using `md5sum -c <file.md5> <file>` but this command worked for me.

Comment: I think this is easiest solution compare to writing if conditions in shell. It's good also it works also another sha functions like sha512sum

Answer (score 4):

The usual bash way would be:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $(md5sum "$file") = 5d40f31729c992b5a0e67490689fe8ff* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
md5sum -c <filename>.zip.md5 <filename>.zip
```

This will tell you Ok if they are the same.

This works with tar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by psusi's answer

```
echo "$(cut -f1 -d' ' your_file.jar.md5) your_file.jar" | md5sum -c -
```

I used `cut` as not all the `md5` are stored in the same way. [Example](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar.md5)